# Listing Outgoing Serial Port in JAVA

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am developing a server application to link arduino with scratch for serial port communication using java net beans. I have added the following jar files in my project

1. Arduino. jar
2. Firmata. jar
3. RXTX jar

I have kept all the respective RXTX files in the respective folders and I am able to run my program without any error but my main aim is to list the com ports in my GUI. But my program is listing all the serial ports except the outgoing serial com port of the BLUETOOTH module (HC05). Do I need to add any other libraries or any other jar files to list the outgoing ports? If I need to add the files kindly let me know the steps for the same.Below is the code for selecting the serial ports and then listing the serial ports.

```
  package listserialports;

    import a4s.A4S;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Vector;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class serialportselection extends javax.swing.JFrame
    {

        static String str;    
        static Vector listData = new Vector(8);

        public serialportselection()
        {
            initComponents();

            addData();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {

            jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
            jComboBox2 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

           setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 102));

            jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft PhagsPa", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
            jLabel1.setText("SELECT THE PORT");

            jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Microsoft PhagsPa", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
            jButton1.setText("CONNECT");
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

            jComboBox2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
            jComboBox2.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Select" }));
            jComboBox2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    jComboBox2ActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new      javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addGap(81, 81, 81)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(126, 126, 126)
                        .addComponent(jButton1)))
                .addContainerGap(67, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(71, 71, 71)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(97, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {

            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
            r.exec("C:\\Program Files\\Scratch 2\\Scratch 2.exe C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\fwdbckpwm12.sb2");

             //r.exec("C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe C:\\Windows\\ss.txt");
            A4S a4sObj = new A4S(new String[]{jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString()});

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(serialportselection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }                                        

    private void jComboBox2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

     public void addData()
    {
         ListSerialPorts listSerPortObj = new ListSerialPorts();//addedline

        listData = listSerPortObj.LoadComPorts();//addedline

        for (int index = 0; index < listData.size(); index++)
        {
             str = (String) listData.get(index);
             System.out.println(str);               
             jComboBox2.addItem(str);
       }       

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new serialportselection().setVisible(true);
            }
        });       

    }


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}

    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package listserialports;

import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Vector;

/*
 * Get list of ports available on this particular computer
 */
public class ListSerialPorts
{
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {

            }

            public Vector LoadComPorts()
            {
                       int totalElements;
                        CommPortIdentifier portId;
                        Enumeration en = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
                        Vector listData = new Vector(8);
                        // Walk through the list of port identifiers and, if it
                               // is a serial port, add its name to the list.
                        while (en.hasMoreElements())
                        {
                                    portId = (CommPortIdentifier) en.nextElement();
                                    if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
                                    {
                                                listData.addElement(portId.getName());
                                    }
                        }

                        totalElements = listData.size();

                        //Iterate through the vector
                        for (int index = 0; index < totalElements; index ++)
                        {
                                    System.out.println(listData.get(index));
                        }

                        return listData;
            }

}
```

Comment: on which environment linux/windows?

Comment: Also add the code and output as well to get better understanding of the question and helpful in answering.

Comment: Use JSSC library this can solve the above mentioned problem